apply function to two pandas columns and assign them back to the original dataframe raises future warning
I have a dataframe with columns for the mean and standard deviation of different distributions of things (along with other columns irrelevant to the question).  I need to apply a function to transform these numbers into mu and sigma to pass into a log normal distribution (what this function does is irrelevant to my question, so I've simplified it).  Example dataframe and function are:
df = pd.DataFrame({'mean': [3, 11, 9, 19, 22],
                   'std': [10, 17, 10, 25, 30]})


def log_normal_transform(mean_std):
    mu = mean_std[0]
    sigma = mean_std[1]
    return mu*2, sigma*2

I want to apply this function to transform the mean and std columns in the dataframe.  I used apply like this:
df[['mean', 'std']].apply(log_normal_transform, axis=1)

which returns a series of tuples with the transformed numbers:
    0
0   (6, 20)
1   (22, 34)
2   (18, 20)
3   (38, 50)
4   (44, 60)

Now when I try to assign this back to the original columns like this:
df[['mean', 'std']] = df[['mean', 'std']].apply(log_normal_transform, axis=1)

I get an error that the columns are not the same length as key (which I understand).  I found this question on how to assign a series of tuples to multiple columns, most answers suggest to convert the series to a list, so I tried this:
df[['mean', 'std']] = df[['mean', 'std']].apply(log_normal_transform, axis=1).values.tolist()

Which does work, however I get a future warning of:
<string>:2: FutureWarning: Series.__getitem__ treating keys as positions is deprecated. In a future version, integer keys will always be treated as labels (consistent with DataFrame behavior). To access a value by position, use `ser.iloc[pos]`

How can I do this without making the future warning come up so my code will still work in future versions?

Problem is in function for select values by positions, solution is use Series.iat or Series.iloc and also use parameter result_type='expand' in DataFrame.apply:

'expand' : list-like results will be turned into columns.

def log_normal_transform(mean_std):
    mu = mean_std.iat[0]
    sigma = mean_std.iat[1]
    return mu*2, sigma*2

Or select columns by labels:
def log_normal_transform(mean_std):
    mu = mean_std['mean']
    sigma = mean_std['std']
    return mu*2, sigma*2


df[['mean', 'std']] = df[['mean', 'std']].apply(log_normal_transform,
                                                axis=1, result_type='expand')
print (df)
   mean  std
0     6   20
1    22   34
2    18   20
3    38   50
4    44   60


I still get a future warning with your code solution

@EmiOB - Do you add result_type='expand' ?

sorry, I didn't see you edited the function as well.  Works now, thank you :) Although if the issue was the function I don't understand why the error only appeared when trying to convert to a list/assign back, just running the apply on it's own didn't produce the futurewarning
